# Javascript Internet Explorer regex problem

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

i have this js code :

```
var str = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$M$List$_rli2$ctl06','')";

alert (str);
var str = str.replace(/\$_rli\d+/, "$_rli" + 7);

alert (str);
```

And in IE it produces me result as follows:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$M$Listjavascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$M$List$_rli2$ctl06','')rli7$ctl06','')
```

while it should work like this:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$M$List$_rli7$ctl06','')
```

and it does in FF, Opera and Chrome.

It Replaces `$_` with whole previous string. No escape sequences seems to help.

What am i Doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the way Internet Explorer handles references in replace.  Use `$$` instead, which should work in all browsers:

```
var str = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$M$List$_rli2$ctl06','')";

alert (str);
var str = str.replace(/\$_rli\d+/, "$$_rli" + 7);

alert (str);
// -> javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$M$List$_rli7$ctl06','')
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to make it a bit clearer you could use an anonymous function that returns the replacement string:

```
var str = str.replace(/\$_rli\d+/, function () { return "$_rli" + 7; });

alert (str);
// -> javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$M$List$_rli7$ctl06','')
```

Comment: thanx that was exactly waht i needed and couldn't find